# Azure App Service - Auto-Heal vs Health Check

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

**Health Check** can restart an instance. **Auto-Heal** also can restart an instance.

So, when should I use **Health Check** and when should I use **Auto-Heal**. Should I use them both together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Health Check feature is pretty basic compared to Auto-Heal. Basically it makes a request to a predefined url and if it does not get a succesful response it will take that instance out of the load balancer pool. If it remain unhealthy it will be replaces with a new instance. It works only if scale-out is applied to the web app.

Auto-Heal is much more sophisticated: instead of pinging a url it can be configured to restart an instance when a certain memory or cpu usage limit is reached, or when the response time is degraded during a certain period.

Comment: Is there any way to restart an instance that fails the health check?